# Concurrently check if string is in slice?

Tags: string, for-loop, go, slice, contains

Generally to check if a string is in slice I write a function with for loop and if statement. but it's really inefficient in cases of large slices of string or struct types. is it possible to make this check concurrent?

Comment: The overhead of starting multiple goroutines to do a simple index sweep is probably not worth it. If you need repeated lookups to be faster, consider indexing.

Answer (score 3):

The concurrent search on sequential data is usually not a great idea, simply because we already have a binary search that scales really well for even billions of records. All you have to do to utilize it is build indexing on top of the slice you are searching in. To build the most trivial indexing, you have to save keys into another slice along with the index of data they are pointing to. Once you have the slice, just sort it by strings, and indexing is done.

You have to perform the binary search on the indexing you just created to be more efficient. This way you have the complexity of O(log N).

Another much simpler option you have is creating the `map[string]int` and inserting all keys along with the indexes. Then find the index inside the map. Which can be O(1) best case.

The important thing to note is that if you have to perform just one search on a given slice, this is not worth it as creating indexing is a lot heavier than linear search.